# Understanding the functional derivative

Tags: distribution-theory, calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

Given a functional $\phi$, it is common in physics texts to see its functional derivative defined as
$$\frac{\delta \phi(f)}{\delta f} = \frac{d }{d\epsilon}\phi(f + \epsilon\psi)\Big|_{\epsilon = 0}$$
where $\psi$ is a test function. However, in Folland's book on quantum field theory, he defines it as
$$\frac{\delta \phi(f)}{\delta f} = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi(f + \epsilon \delta_x) - \phi(f)}{\epsilon}$$
where $\delta_x$ is the delta-function with pole at $x$. Folland does point out that the above is only a formal definition.

My first question is if $\phi$ belongs to the dual of some function space, how is it permitted to have it act on another functional (in this case, the delta-function)? Secondly, what is stopping the above definitions from being rigorous? Is there anyway to make them rigorous?

Comment: Can you give some example of $\phi$ that you have in mind?

Comment: @ArcticChar In physics they take $\phi$ to be the Lagrangian. So in the simplest case we may have something such as $\phi(f) = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{f} - maf$, where $m$ and $a$ are constants and the dot represents the time derivative.